# Exoplayer Controllers visibility cannot be handled programatically in Android

Tags: android, exoplayer, google-developers-console

I used PLayerView of Exoplayer for playing videos. Everything worked fine. I want to use forward button/rewind button inside controller layout. I used exo_rew and exo_ffwd. But i am not able to change the visibility of exo_rew, exo_ffwd. I want the rewind button to be always shown but the forward button only shown sometimes depending on my usecase.

Can someone help me on how to play with the visibility of controllers.

Comment: What have you tried? Post the code.

Answer (score 0):

First design custom control for your exoplayer then put your forward button in any layout like LinearLayout now you can  easily hide your button visibility

```
<LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/exo_ffwd_control"
      android:orientation="vertical">
   <ImageButton
        android:id="@id/exo_ffwd"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.FastForward"
        android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:tintMode="src_in" />
</LinearLayout>

    if(<your condition>){
         exo_ffwd_control.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work